# Cannot access ID from method in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a card in which I can place a scroll view on that appears on the viewdecks screen after the user has logged in to do this I called the ViewDecks.ShowDecks() method from inside of the login class, I think this is creating a problem as when I run the code I get this error: deck_list = self.ids.deck_scroll
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'.I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import mysql.connector
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class Login(Screen):
    def sign(self):
        if self.ids.user.text == "" or self.ids.passw.text == "" or self.ids.email.text == "":
            dialog = MDDialog(
                text="All fields required",
                buttons=[MDRaisedButton(text='OK', on_release=lambda x: dialog.dismiss())]
            )
            dialog.open()

        else:
            try:
                mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host="localhost",
                    user="root",
                    passwd="root",
                    database="mydb"
                )
                mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            except:
                dialog = MDDialog(
                    text="Error, connection is not established try again later",
                    buttons=[MDRaisedButton(text='OK', on_release=lambda x: dialog.dismiss())]
                )
                dialog.open()
                return
            query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s"
            mycursor.execute(query, (self.ids.user.text,))
            existing = mycursor.fetchone()
            if existing != None:
                dialog = MDDialog(
                    text="Username already in use",
                    buttons=[MDRaisedButton(text='OK', on_release=lambda x: dialog.dismiss())]
                )
                dialog.open()
            else:
                mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(username,pass,email) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",
                                 (self.ids.user.text, self.ids.passw.text, self.ids.email.text))
                mydb.commit()

    def log(self):
        if self.ids.user.text == "" or self.ids.passw.text == "":
            dialog = MDDialog(
                text="Username and Password required.",
                buttons=[MDRaisedButton(text='OK', on_release=lambda x: dialog.dismiss())]
            )
            dialog.open()
        else:
            try:
                mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host="localhost",
                    user="root",
                    passwd="root",
                    database="mydb"
                    )
                mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            except:
                dialog = MDDialog(
                    text="Error, connection is not established try again later",
                    buttons=[MDRaisedButton(text='OK', on_release=lambda x: dialog.dismiss())]
                )
                dialog.open()
                return
            query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s AND pass=%s"
            mycursor.execute(query, (self.ids.user.text, self.ids.passw.text))
            existing = mycursor.fetchone()
            if existing == None:
                dialog = MDDialog(
                    text="Invalid username or password",
                    buttons=[MDRaisedButton(text='OK', on_release=lambda x: dialog.dismiss())]
                )
                dialog.open()
            else:
                self.user_id=existing[0]
                self.manager.current="deck_view"
                ViewDecks.ShowDecks(self)
                print(self.user_id)

    def clear(self):
        self.ids.user.text = ""
        self.ids.passw.text = ""
        self.ids.email.text = ""


class ViewDecks(Screen):

    def ShowDecks(self):
        try:
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                passwd="root",
                database="mydb"
            )
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        except:
            dialog = MDDialog(
                text="Error, connection is not established try again later",
                buttons=[MDRaisedButton(text='OK', on_release=lambda x: dialog.dismiss())]
            )
            dialog.open()
        mycursor.execute('SELECT deck_name FROM decks WHERE user_id = %s', (self.user_id,))
        decks = mycursor.fetchall()
        deck_list = self.ids.deck_scroll
        for deck_name in decks:
            deck_card = MDCard(orientation='horizontal', size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 300))
            deck_card.add_widget(MDLabel(text=deck_name[0]))
            deck_list.add_widget(deck_card)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Myapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'DeepPurple'

        return Builder.load_file('flashcards.kv')


Myapp().run()
```

kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    Login
    ViewDecks
<Login>:

    MDCard:
        size_hint:None, None
        size:300,400
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        padding:25
        spacing:25
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDLabel:
            id:welcome_label
            text:"Welcome"
            font_size:40
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height:self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y:15

        MDTextField:
            id:user
            mode:"round"
            hint_text: "username"
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width:205
            font_size:18
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}

        MDTextField:
            id:passw
            mode:"round"
            hint_text: "password"
            icon_right: "eye-off"
            size_hint_x: None
            width:205
            font_size:18
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
            password:True

        MDTextField:
            id:email
            mode:"round"
            hint_text: "email(only for signup)"
            icon_right: "email"
            size_hint_x: None
            width:205
            font_size:18
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}

        Widget:
            size_hint_x:None
            height:10

        BoxLayout:

            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: "Signup"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: 15
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.2, "center_y":0.7}
                size_hint_x: 0.05
                on_press:root.sign()

            Widget:
                size_hint_x:None
                width:10

            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: "Login"
                text_color: "white"
                font_size: 15
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.7, "center_y":0.7}
                size_hint_x: 0.05
                on_press:root.log()

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Clear"
            text_color: "white"
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            on_press: root.clear()

<ViewDecks>:
    name:"deck_view"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation :'horizontal'

        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                id:deck_scroll
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly calling the `ShowDecks()` method in the line:

```
ViewDecks.ShowDecks(self)
```

You should call that method using the instance of `ViewDecks` that is in your app. Try replacing that line with:

```
viewdeck = self.manager.get_screen("deck_view")
viewdeck.ShowDecks()
```